# lightweight openid error: (https or curl must be enabled)

Tags: php, openid, wamp, zend-framework

The openid library give me the error of:

> You must have either https wrappers or curl enabled.

What does it mean...?

I am using zend on wamp server.....

Thanks in advance....

Comment: well, I'm not a scientist or anything, but if I had to guess, I'd say it means you need to have HTTPS wrappers or cURL enabled. Just a shot in the dark.

Comment: i know the meaning... but actually what i mean is how to enabled https in wamp or programatically can we remove this exception from library...

Comment: Have you tried adding or uncommenting `extension=php_curl.dll` or `extension=php_openssl.dll` to your php.ini?

Comment: no i haven't tried this... but i think this will be simple if someone already try it....let me tried that also...

Comment: @vstm.....you are right now that message is not showing... thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Uncomment the below line in the `php.ini` file to enable curl (remove the semicolon at the beginning of the line):

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

Comment: I did that. But I'm still getting the error.

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'You must have either https wrappers or curl enabled.' in C:\wamp\www\MyApp\application\views\openid.php on line 94`